# Extracting mean data for quadrats over a spatial raster

Tags: r, extract, raster, spatial

I'll provide a bit of a background. I'm not 100% sure that the path I'm currently following to get the output I'm after is correct, but I've used a very similar process to get count data for telemetry pings within each quadrat.

I want to

- divide my study area waterways into a series of 20m2 and 50m2 quadrats
- then I want to assign each quadrat with a mean biomass value extracted from the biomass raster
- for anywhere there is a quadrat that doesn't overlap with part of the biomass raster, just give the value of 0  (this is the part where I currently need help)
- then I want to export that as a spatial raster for which I'll then be running analysis to compare the mean value of biomass for each quadrat against the count data for each quadrat

```
telemetry <- read.csv("Outputs/2015/2015-nov-tsdata-1m.csv")

biomass <- raster("GIS/Interpolations/IDWBio/15NovIDWBio.tif")

#############################
# set class for id and date #
#############################

telemetry$id <- as.factor(telemetry$id)
telemetry$DateTime <- as.POSIXct(telemetry$DateTime, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

######################################################
# Set Spatial Points and Coordinate Reference System #
######################################################

telemetry.sp <- SpatialPoints(coords=cbind(telemetry$lon, telemetry$lat), 
                            proj4string = CRS("+init=epsg:4326"))

proj4string(biomass) <- projection(telemetry.sp)

telemetry.sp$id <- telemetry$id    #import Sat Tag ID

#####################################################################
# Import ShapeFile of Focus Study Area and set CRS same as sat data #
#####################################################################

StudyArea <- readOGR("GIS/ShapeFiles/Landscape/PelicanBanks.shp")

proj4string(StudyArea) <- projection(telemetry.sp)

##################################
# Turn the Shapefile into Raster #
##################################

rStudyArea20 <- raster(StudyArea)
rStudyArea50 <- raster(StudyArea)

#############################################################################
# Set Resolution / Cell Size of Raster, this will impact Quadrat size later #
#############################################################################

res(rStudyArea20) <- 0.0002
res(rStudyArea50) <- 0.0005

#### 0.0005 = 50m2,  0.0002 = 20m2

###################################################################################
# Add ShapeFile of StudyArea to above Raster, defining Rasters spatial attributes #
###################################################################################

rStudyArea20 <- rasterize(StudyArea, rStudyArea20)
rStudyArea50 <- rasterize(StudyArea, rStudyArea50)


####################################################
# Build 'quadrats' around our predefined Cell Size #
####################################################

quadrat20 <- as(rStudyArea20, "SpatialPolygons")
quadrat50 <- as(rStudyArea50, "SpatialPolygons")

### original biomass raster is over a very large area, so to minimise computing time I'm creating a 
### subset of a smaller area while I'm trying to work out the code

biomass.mask <- mask(biomass, StudyArea)

##################################################
# Summarise the mean biomass within each quadrat #
##################################################

bioQuadrats20 <- rasterize(biomass.mask, rStudyArea20, fun='mean', background=0)
bioQuadrats50 <- rasterize(biomass.mask, rStudyArea50, fun='mean', background=0)

### this is where my train of thought falls apart and I receive the following error
```

** Unable to find an inherited method for function ‘rasterize’ for signature ‘"RasterLayer", "RasterLayer"’ **

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the last part can be done by `extract`ing the values of the biomass within the polygon. You don't need `mask`. You can try this:

```
library(exactextractr)
library(sf)
quadrat20 <- as(rStudyArea20, "SpatialPolygons")
quadrat50 <- as(rStudyArea50, "SpatialPolygons")

quadrat20.sf <- st_as_sf(quadrat20)
quadrat50.sf <- st_as_sf(quadrat50)

extraction <-  exact_extract(biomass, quadrat20.sf,"mean")
```

the function `exact_extract` comes with the [exactextractr](https://github.com/isciences/exactextractr) package and is the fastest method to extract values from raster within polygons. The function also returns the pixel coverage fraction by the polygons, so you can easily handle the partially covered pixel. In addition, the built-in summary functions are super fast and ignores the NAs by default.